# way to combine all commits into a single commit using libgit2

Tags: c++, git, libgit2

I want to combine all commits into one for removes the history. I know that it's possible in Git command line, but I did not found a way in libgit2 yet.

I'm using libgit2 in the latest version, compiled by me in C++.

What do you suggest?

Comment: @nulltoken could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to think about this. On the command line you might do something like this:

```
git reset --soft <some-ancestor-commit-ish>
git commit -m "This commit combines some history."
```

The soft reset moves the current branch to point to some ancestor commit without changing the working directory and index. So now you have all of the changes introduced by those commits staged and you can commit them as a new combined commit. Those two steps can be translated directly to libgit2 with something like:

```
git_reset(repo, ancestor_commit, GIT_RESET_SOFT, NULL);
git_commit_create(...);
```

Comment: I'll test it, but I'm not sure about this, because I want remove the history. Do you know rebase command line with squash? I want something like that on libgit2, because it squash the commits and remove them to create a new one

Comment: Rebase doesn't remove history. It writes a new history and leaves the old commits unreachable. The procedure I described does essentially the same thing. Unreachable commits will only be pruned after they get old enough and you run something like `git gc`. As far as I know, libgit2 doesn't even have a way to remove unreachable objects from the database.